# Key not found in response array for php and my chart is empty for my javaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, highcharts

i'm doing this school project. can you help me?

The project consists in the creation of a web interface which, by querying an endpoint, is able to:
log in with a registered user to retrieve an authentication token.
once the token has been recovered, show two graphs that update independently of each other at regular intervals, without having to reload the page
The end-point must be created in object-oriented PHP, and must in turn query, using the php cURL library,

Specifications Endpoints

url: https://cool/login/

request format: x-www-form-urlencoded

response format: json

error example: {status: 123, message:'error description'}

LOGIN:

http:POST method

parameters: email, password

response example: {status: 0, message:'login completed', token: '...'}

GRAPHIC DATA:

http method: GET

headers: tokens

parameters:graph

response example: {status: 0, dataset: [{email: test1@test.it, data: 10}, {...}]}

this is my login html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>My Login Interface</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="login-box">
        <!-- Login form -->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body login-card-body">
        <form id="login-form" method="post" action="home.php">
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"><br>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-envelope"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          
        </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php page where speak with the server:

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = "";
$password = "";
$response = "";
$chart_url = "";

// Check if the form was submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); 
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
} 


$response = curl_exec($ch);
$token = $response;

$response_array = json_decode($response, true);
$_SESSION['token'] = $response_array['token'];
if(isset($response_array['chart_url'])){
    $chart_url = $response_array['chart_url'];
} else {
    echo 'Error: chart_url key not found in response array';
}
$chart_url = "https://cool/login/3?token=" . $response_array['token'];
if ($response_array['status'] === 0) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $response_array['token'];
    
    //if the authentication was successful, include the HTML file that contains the chart
    require_once("graph_test.html");
    //pass the chart url to the iframe
    echo "<script>document.getElementById('chart-iframe').src = '$chart_url';</script>";
    echo "<script>var token = '$token';</script>";
} else {
    echo '<p>Incorrect email or password</p>';
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

so i suceded in getting the token and got redirected to my graph.html

this is my graph.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart-container"></div>
       <iframe id="chart-iframe" src="https://cool/login/?token=<?php echo urlencode($_SESSION['token']); ?>&graph=1"></iframe> 
      </div>
<script>
    // Get the iframe element
    var chartIframe = document.getElementById("chart-iframe");

    // Set the src attribute of the iframe to the chart URL
    chartIframe.src = "https://cool/login/?token=<?php echo urlencode($_SESSION['token']); ?>&graph=1";
    // Get the token from PHP
    var token = '<?php echo $token; ?>';
    document.getElementById('chart-iframe').src = '$chart_url';
        // Set the URL of the API endpoint
        var apiUrl = "https://cool/login/?token=" + token + "&graph=1";

        // Initialize the chart
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart-container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Chart Title'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Y-axis Label'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Series Name',
                data: []  // Data will be populated here
            }]
        });
// Create an XMLHttpRequest object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Open the request and set the headers
xhr.open("GET", chartUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

// Function to handle the response
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        // Use the response data to update the chart
        chart.series[0].setData(response.data);
    } else {
        console.log("Error: " + xhr.status);
    }
};

// Send the request
xhr.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But i have encontuered a couple of problems.

the graph.html gives me the: Error: chart_url key not found in response array
plus my chart is completely empty and i can't understand why.

The error message "Error: chart_url key not found in response array" is usually indicating that the $response_array variable doesn't contain a key named "chart_url". so if i want to use the token that you received from the API in the iframe's URL, i change this line:

```
$chart_url = $response_array['chart_url'];
```

to this line:

```
$chart_url = "https://cloud.fatturapro.click/junior2023?token=" . $response_array['token'];
```

This will append the token that you received from the API to the URL of the iframe. You can test the iframe by adding this line at the end of my php file

```
echo "<script>document.getElementById('chart-iframe').src = '$chart_url';</script>";
```

but than again it didn't work.
I am really a beginner in php.

for the other problem

i've tried to make an additional API call to get the data:

```
//create an XMLHttpRequest object
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  //open the request and set the headers
  xhr.open("GET", chart_url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
  
  //function to handle the response
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      //update the chart with the retrieved data
      chart.update({
        series: [{
          data: data
        }]
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Error: " + xhr.status);
    }
  };
  
  //send the request
  xhr.send();
```

but it didn't work.
Could you help?

Comment: `$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cool/login/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
    ]));`
my php had this but i couldn't put it it becase stackoverflow was flagging my post as spam

Comment: If I understood correctly, your code relies on the fact that there is a key in a response from some server. And error happens when this key is not present. Could you call var_dump($response_array), instead of echo'ing an error message? Maybe if you will see the whole response, it will be clear why the expected key is not present.

Comment: hi ilia! thanks for the reply. it gave me this:                                                             
 array(3) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(42) "login completed token valid for 5 minutes" ["token"]=> string(32) "tokenstuff" }

Comment: so there is no such key 'chat_url', right? Then, why do you expect it to be present there?

Comment: Hi @Gio0sol, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ilia mentioned after calling `var_dump($response_array)` and esamining the result:
`array(3) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["message"]=> string(42) "login completed token valid for 5 minutes" ["token"]=> string(32) "tokenstuff" }`

It is clear that there is no key `chat_url` the code was flawed from the start.